# Show Attachment File Names in a List View

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, export-to-excel

**I'm trying to replace the SharePoint 2013 attachment paperclip icons with the actual NAME of the attached document.**

When I export a SharePoint (2013) list to an Excel spreadsheet, instead of listing the name of the document (which is a hyperlink to the document), it will only show "Attachments" in the column instead of the document name.

I just want a spreadsheet that has a column with the name of the attachment.

Any suggestions?

Attached is a snap of the SP data prior to exporting:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Download JQuery Api and upload js file to Site Assets library.

Save the below code as JS file and upload it to Site Assets library.

```
(function () {

// Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it output render  

var attachmentsFiledContext = {};

attachmentsFiledContext.Templates = {};

attachmentsFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {
     
    "Attachments": { "View": AttachmentsFiledTemplate }
};

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(attachmentsFiledContext);

})();


// This function provides the rendering logic for list view 
function AttachmentsFiledTemplate(ctx) {
var itemId = ctx.CurrentItem.ID;
var listName = ctx.ListTitle;       
return getAttachments(listName, itemId);
}

//get attachments field properties
function getAttachments(listName,itemId) {

var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var requestUri = url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + itemId + ")/AttachmentFiles";
var str = "";
// execute AJAX request
$.ajax({
    url: requestUri,
    type: "GET",
    headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
            str += "<a href='" + data.d.results[i].ServerRelativeUrl + "'>" + data.d.results[i].FileName + "</a>";
            if (i != data.d.results.length - 1) {
                str += "<br/>";
            }                
        }          
    },
    error: function (err) {
        //alert(err);
    }
});
return str;
}
```

Edit the Miscellaneous section of list web part, Add the following URL into the JS Link textbox.

```
~site/SiteAssets/jquery-1.11.2.min.js|~site/SiteAssets/ShowAttachments.js
```

[image]

Test result:

[image]

I have post a detailed answer on Microsoft Q&A: [Export a SharePoint List with Name of Attachments](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/466527/export-a-sharepoint-list-with-name-of-attachments.html?childToView=467333#answer-467333), you can take a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the below PowerShell script as an admin:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
#Get the SPWeb
$web = Get-SPWeb -identity “http://sp/sites/echo/”
#Get the SPList
$list = $web.Lists[“TargetList”]
$ListItemCollection = @()

 $list.Items | foreach {
    $attachmentCollection = $_.Attachments
    $folder = $web.GetFolder($attachmentCollection.UrlPrefix);
    foreach ($file in $folder.Files)
    {  
        #Write-Host $file.Name
        $AttachmentName = $file.Name
        Write-Host $AttachmentName     
    }

 $ExportItem = New-Object PSObject
 $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name “Title” -value $_[“Title”]
 $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name “Choice” -value $_[“Choice”]
 $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name “Date” -value $_[“Date”]
 $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name “Account” -value $_[“Account”]
 $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name “Attachment” -value $_[“Attachments”]
 if($_[“Attachments”]){
 $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name “AttachmentName” -value $AttachmentName
 }
 $ListItemCollection += $ExportItem
}

Write-Host “Copying data from list to Excel”
$ListItemCollection | Export-CSV “C:\temp\TestMyList.csv”                   
#Dispose the web Object
$web.Dispose()
```

[image]

[image]